# Unpivot use in Function

Tags: db2, db2-400

```
Select * from Emp;

Emp_Id Emp_Name
1      John
2      Peter


Expected Result:

Element_Name Element_Value
Emp_Id1      1
Emp_Id2      2
Emp_Name1    John
Emp_Name2    Peter
```

Can anyone suggest how to get in DB2 Function.

In Procedure means can get with the help of "Lateral" keyword.

but need in Function.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T(Emp_Id, Emp_Name) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'John')
, (2, 'Peter')
)
SELECT 
  'Emp_Id'||TRIM(CHAR(Emp_Id)) AS Element_Name 
, TRIM(CHAR(Emp_Id)) AS Element_Value
FROM T
  UNION ALL
SELECT 
  'Emp_Name'||TRIM(CHAR(Emp_Id)) AS Element_Name 
, Emp_Name AS Element_Value
FROM T;

|ELEMENT_NAME       |ELEMENT_VALUE|
|-------------------|-------------|
|Emp_Id1            |1            |
|Emp_Id2            |2            |
|Emp_Name1          |John         |
|Emp_Name2          |Peter        |
```

I didn't get the question "how to get in DB2 Function"...